# Rails - Session Variable Does Not Persist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to save the state of my side-menu in rails session variable, so that if my user collapses the side-menu, that collapsed state will persist when the view is changed. I have my js set up so that an uncollapsed state will send "0" through to the controller, and if the side menu is in a collapsed state, the ajax will send a "1" through to the controller action. If the controller action receives "1", I want that session variable set in my app.

I currently have an ajax request to the respective controller action, and the collapsed side-nav is sending a "1" through successfully, but the session variable does not seem to persist. Here is what I see in the console when the side-nav is collapsed:

**CONSOLE:**
(When the side-nav is collapsed)

```
Started POST "/dashboard/side_nav_state" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-06-02 15:58:08 +0000
Processing by DashboardController#side_nav_state as */*
  Parameters: {"hide_side_nav"=>"1"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

(When the side-nav is expanded)

```
Started POST "/dashboard/side_nav_state" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-06-02 16:02:56 +0000
Processing by DashboardController#side_nav_state as */*
  Parameters: {"hide_side_nav"=>"0"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**JavaScript:**

The `sendSideNav();` function actually sends the 1 or the 0 through to the controller. As you can see, the `collapsedSideNav();` function sends the 1. If you look at the `sendSideNav();` function you can see that the 1 is passed through to the data key value pair in the ajax request.

```
// collapsible side-nav functionality
function collapsedSideNav(){
  $('.side-nav').toggle(300);
  $('#collapse-side-nav').css('display', 'none');
  $('#expand-side-nav').css('display', 'inherit');
  $('.container').animate({
    'padding-left' : 0
  }, "slow");
  $('.row').css({
    'max-width' : '98%',
    'margin-left' : '1.15rem'
  });
  sendSideNavStatus(1);
};

// expandable side-nav functionality
function expandedSideNav(){
  $('.side-nav').toggle(325);
  $('#expand-side-nav').css('display', 'none');
  $('#collapse-side-nav').css('display', 'inherit');
  $('.container').animate({
    'padding-left' : 200
  }, "slow");
  $('.row').animate({
    'max-width' : '95%',
    'margin-left' : 'auto'
  });
  sendSideNavStatus(0);
};

// sends the state of the side-menu (if not default) to the controller so it can be stored in a session
// 1 for true, and 0 for false.
function sendSideNavStatus(trueOrFalse){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/dashboard/side_nav_state',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {hide_side_nav: trueOrFalse}
  });
};

// DOM Events for collapsing and expanding side-nav
$('#collapse-side-nav').click(function() {
  collapsedSideNav();
});
$('#expand-side-nav').click(function() {
  expandedSideNav();
});
```

**ROUTES**

```
post 'dashboard/side_nav_state'
```

**CONTROLLER ACTION**

```
def side_nav_state
    session[:hide_side_nav] = params[:hide_side_nav] == "1" 
    render json: {success: true}
end
```

**EDIT**:

I should note that all of this is happening in my dashboard controller. I want this session to persist regardless of what controller I am in. Is that possible? I know you cannot route to your application controller which is why I set up the logic to the dashboard controller. I am not sure what the solution is here.

Comment: What is this line doing: session[:hide_side_nav] = params[:hide_side_nav] == "1"

Comment: It looks wrong to me, like the session var would never be set, unless I'm ready it wrong

Comment: What I am attempting to do with that line is set the session variable if the ajax sends a "1". I'm positive this is the line where my error is as well, I just honestly am not sure how to set this up correctly, and I have not used rails sessions before. How would you go about setting up that method if it were you, @RichardAE?

Comment: @RichardAE You're reading it wrong ;) It sets the session var to the result of the equality expression. But it's the wrong expression if the OP wants a 0 or 1, maybe that's what you meant.

Comment: @RichardAE I have tried sesssion[:hide_side_nav] ||= "1" as well.

Comment: Can you post the code that actually tries to use that session variable please?

Comment: @RichardAE I should note that this logic is happening in my dashboard controller. I am wanting the session to persist regardless of what controller action I am viewing, even if that controller action is in a different controller all together. Could that be where my error in judgement is?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that ends up having this problem and can't find an answer, I have finally come to conclusion on how to resolve the problem.

I have found that rails sessions are primarily used for backend logic (user authentication, user preferences, etc etc). The problem with my code above was that *my javascript did not receive the session variable anywhere.*. The session variable was setting correctly and persisting, but because I needed the javascript acted upon by the session variable, having the variable was kind of a moot point.

One solution could be for me to set up a `post` end point and create a second ajax request. But this would create a lot of extra code including another end point, and another controller action, along with the javascript.

Because Rails doesn't really provide a good way to have your javascript interact with session variables, for this particular problem I decided that it would be better to handle the problem 100% on the client side and create a browser cookie. I used the cookie.js library and set the cookie up accordingly. My finalized code ended up looking like this:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  Cookies.get();
  initializeSideNav();
});

// Checks the current status of the side menu
function initializeSideNav() {
  if (Cookies.get("collapsed-side-nav") === "true") {
    collapsedSideNav();
  }
}

// collapsible side-nav functionality
function collapsedSideNav(){
  $('.side-nav').toggle(300);
  $('#collapse-side-nav').css('display', 'none');
  $('#expand-side-nav').css('display', 'inherit');
  $('.container').animate({
    'padding-left' : 0
  }, "slow");
  $('.row').css({
    'max-width' : '98%',
    'margin-left' : '1.15rem'
  });
  Cookies.set('collapsed-side-nav', true, {path: '/'})
  console.log(Cookies.get());
};

// expandable side-nav functionality
function expandedSideNav(){
  $('.side-nav').toggle(325);
  $('#expand-side-nav').css('display', 'none');
  $('#collapse-side-nav').css('display', 'inherit');
  $('.container').animate({
    'padding-left' : 200
  }, "slow");
  $('.row').animate({
    'max-width' : '95%',
    'margin-left' : 'auto'
  });
  Cookies.set('collapsed-side-nav', false, {path: '/'});
  console.log(Cookies.get());
};

// DOM Events for collapsing and expanding side-nav
$('#collapse-side-nav').click(function() {
  collapsedSideNav();
});
$('#expand-side-nav').click(function() {
  expandedSideNav();
});
```